# How do you run as sudo in the web terminal in Theia

Tags: theia

How do you run as root in the web terminal of Theia?

Just want to update golang - one other way is to update/copy the Dockerfile: https://github.com/theia-ide/theia-apps/blob/master/theia-go-docker/Dockerfile

But it would be nice to run as root in the terminal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `RUN adduser...` and `USER theia`. BTW there is a better image now which support go vscode extension: https://github.com/theia-ide/theia-apps/pull/146 So you even can debug Go.